# In AWS ECS I'm seeing multiple ways to pass secrets into environment variables, are these methods interchangeable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

Specifically this:

[image: environment key/value pairs]

Where the jwt_pub_keys_secret is formatted like:
`test/jwt/publicKey/auth-device-manager`

And the spring_datasource one is formatted like:
`arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:*************:secret:test/mysql/password/myservice`

My question is, if I change the spring_datasource one from `ValueFrom` to `Value` can I express it in the form of a normal path like the jwt_pub_keys one, or is there a specific reason that the datasource needs to use `ValueFrom` like it does?

Answer (score 3):

When you specify `Value` then you are setting value directly. This is done for general environment variables, **NOT** for secrets.

When you specify `Value From` then you are telling ECS to go get the value from either AWS Secrets Manager or AWS Parameter Store. You are specifying the ARN of the secret to go retrieve. ECS will then look up the value of that secret, and place the value in the environment variable when it creates the ECS task.

---

In your case ECS is just passing the `"test/jwt/publicKey/auth-device-manager"` string directly into your ECS task, without doing any sort of secret value lookup. If that is the ID of a secret in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store, then your code would have to be doing that lookup to get the actual value of the secret.